# How the web server and application server work in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A rails application has its own server but my question is how this web server talk or connect with the route file rails applications.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a very big question, but in a nutshell...

There's a component of the rails application suite called Rack. It processes incoming requests and outgoing responses. Rack itself organizes a number of "middleware" apps, each of which processes one aspect of the request/response.

The routes file defines the behaviour of ActionDispatch by defining how urls map to "rack endpoints". So if you type `rails routes` into the rails console, you'll see how each url maps to the controllers and their methods ("rack endpoints") in your app.